# Count IDs are less than the others in a table MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table sql like this

```
post_id    point    user_id
0          1.5      1
1          1.0      1
2          1.5      2
3          0.0      3
4          1.5      4
5          1.0      1
6          1.0      2
7          1.5      1
8          0.0      2
9          1.5      3
```

According to the above table:

1. **User 1** has **4** posts - the most posts user in table.
2. **User 2** has **3** posts => Need to add 1 post.
3. **User 3** has **2** posts => Need to add 2 posts.
4. **User 4** has **1** post => Need to add 3 post.

How can I find out which users have less posts than the **most posts user in table** then update the table like this

```
post_id    point    user_id
0          1.5      1
1          1.0      1
2          1.5      2
3          0.0      3
4          1.5      4
5          1.0      1
6          1.0      2
7          1.5      1
8          0.0      2
9          1.5      3
NULL       NULL     2
NULL       NULL     3
NULL       NULL     3
NULL       NULL     4
NULL       NULL     4
NULL       NULL     4
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: _I really don't know how to count the rows in MySQL._ [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=myysql+count+records&oq=myysql+count+records)

Comment: In the expected result, the last 3 entries `user_id` is 4 or 1?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Do you need second highest poster user ? Let suppose a user A have posted 4 times and a user B have posted 3 times, so you need user B ? Right ?

Comment: @Arulkumar Sorry. Edited the expected result

Comment: @AbdulrehmanSheikh Yes. Actually I need all users have less posts than the highest poster, then balance the posts by adding more rows.

Comment: select user_id, count(user_id) as totalPosts from tablename where count(user_id) < MAX(count(user_id) ) order by count(user_id) desc group by user_id

Comment: Try this it can be useful for you

Comment: @AbdulrehmanSheikh thanks but how can I get the number posts those users need to add more ? For example user 2 need more **1 post**, user 3 need more **2 posts** ?

Comment: user 2 and user 3 need to post more 1 and 2 posts to reach equals to the higher poster user? right ?

Comment: @AbdulrehmanSheikh yes, that's right

Comment: select user_id, count(user_id) as totalPosts, ((select MAX(count(user_id) )  from tablename group by user_id) - count(user_id)) as needToAddMore from tablename where count(user_id) < MAX(count(user_id) ) order by count(user_id) desc group by user_id

Comment: Try something like this, let me create a table and then test it for you on my localhost

Comment: @MCN in your case, in your provided data set there is the highest posts are 8 so the user who have posted 8 times is not selected in the query. All other users who have posted less than 8 posts are listed. the remainings column have total number of posts are left to meet the exact highest poster count of posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, can help you must:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(post_id) as postIds, SUM(point) as totalPoints,
 count(user_id) as totalPosts , 
((SELECT count(user_id) as maxtotal FROM `posts` GROUP BY posts.user_id ORDER BY maxtotal DESC LIMIT 1) - count(user_id)) as totalRemaining 
FROM `posts` 

GROUP BY posts.user_id 
HAVING totalPosts < (SELECT count(user_id) as maxtotal FROM `posts` 
GROUP BY posts.user_id ORDER BY maxtotal DESC LIMIT 1) 
ORDER BY totalPosts DESC
```

Its tested and working fine, check screenshot as well.
[image]

Comment: @MCN in your case, in your provided data set there is the highest posts are 8 so the user who have posted 8 times is not selected in the query. All other users who have posted less than 8 posts are listed. the remainings column have total number of posts are left to meet the exact highest poster count of posts.

Comment: My pleasure bro,